# Show matrix cells as tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, user-interface

I want to show a matrix cells in the form of tiles. When one of the tiles hovered, a plugin should highlight a rectangle with tiles, located to the left and above. All other tiles should to be darkened.
Please advice any JQuery plugins what will do this job or it's part. Especially ones with a nice animation.
[highlighted tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf2eY.gif)

Comment: Your image shows the tiles above and to the left being darkened, which is opposite your description. Also, your image does not show which "tile" is hovered over, so we're left to guess.

Comment: Is the inversion so important? Hovered tile is in 4th row and 2nd column. Highlighted tiles is in [0, 0] - [4, 2]